# I can receive all PADI packets for PPPoE connections of my ISP, is that a problem?

Tags: network, attacks

for debugging why my router wasn't connecting to pppoe i've tried to connect via the pc, it worked, then i started wireshark just to see what was going on, and i've seen that i can read all the PADI packets from ISP's other clients, now i'm thinking, is that a security problem? Can another user respond with a PADO packet and complete a pppoe session acting as gateway and maybe also sniffing pppoe credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I remember an Article on the German news site heise.de which described a similar vulnerability at a German DSL provider:

- [Wenn der Nachbar heimlich mitsurft](http://www.heise.de/netze/meldung/Wenn-der-Nachbar-heimlich-mitsurft-153559.html)  ([Google-Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.heise.de/netze/meldung/Wenn-der-Nachbar-heimlich-mitsurft-153559.html))
- [Fremde Daten per ADSL-Kurzschluss](http://www.heise.de/netze/artikel/In-Nachbars-Netz-221747.html)   ([Google-Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.heise.de/netze/artikel/In-Nachbars-Netz-221747.html))

The problem in that case was, that not only all the PPPoE packets were visible, but all packets. So if connected directly to a Windows computer, Windows would autoconfigure a private ip-address in the 169.0.0.0/8 range. Furthermore since this is another interface, Firewall rules for the internet-connection were not applied, exposing the Windows Network file and printer sharing.

So this is the next thing to check.

Comment: I've just tried to run a pppoe-server and got full padi, pado, padr, pads handshake, ending with a padt due "RP-PPPoE: Child pppd process terminated" maybe because the server isn't configured for authentication or other things. Usually i can just see padi, just because they're in broadcast, but i can still send packets with the correct mac to another client. Btw i'm using a kind of wimax connection, not a normal dsl service.

Comment: You think that's a security problem?

Comment: Btw, i cannot directly connect to others pc because i just know the mac and not the ip (due the padi broadcast) so i can just send low level packets